# Make a curve be exactly a perfect slice of a circle

Tags: geometry

I've a curve which is part of a train track. I would like to make this piece a perfect "slice" of a circle. Is this possible?

I'm really new to Blender and modelling (in general), so I'm sorry if this is an easy task.

Here's the code:

> http://pastebin.com/p0cKF7ED

Note the object should still be a mesh of triangles (triangulated).

As you can see from the following picture:
[image]

the curve is not totally and exactly in the circle.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

1. Model the train Rail as linear, uncurved Shape.
2. Insert a Circle with add-mesh-Circle. Use the Number of verts as a multiplier of 360 degrees,  e.g. 36 verts.
3. Delete as many verts as you Need until you geht the Desired bow.
4. In Object Mode,  use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to convert the Circle bow Into a Curve.
5. Apply a Curve modifier to the linear Rail from 1., Using the curve from 4. as Curve.

Be aware of that both objects Need to have applied scale,  rotation and Location.

I Hope this Helps.

Kind regards,  Karl Andreas Groß